# Intellij Command Used for "Refrsh SBT Project"

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm wondering what is the actual sbt command that Intellij is executing when I use "Refresh sbt project" from the sbt window. I would like to understand how the same command can be issued from the sbt shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IntelliJ Scala plugin ships with the [sbt-structure](https://github.com/JetBrains/sbt-structure) sbt plugin, which gets automatically loaded with sbt shell sessions that you start from the IDE. When you enable sbt shell for imports, a refresh simply writes commands similar to these to the sbt shell:

```
> set org.jetbrains.sbt.StrcutureKeys.sbtStructureOptions in Global := "prettyPrint download"
> */*:dumpStructureTo structure.xml
```

To actually import the project structure, IntelliJ also runs an additional step which does not happen in sbt.